# Mask a Raster layer in QGIS using a vector layer with multiple polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, zonal-statistics

I would like to extract statistics from a raster file based on a land cover classification vector file, however the land covers (features) are not contiguous (see pic).

In the example below, I would like to calculate a 90th percentile of all pixels in the "12" feature of the overlying vector file. I am looking for a single value, not a 90th percentile for each of the polygons of feature "12".

I can't figure how to do this and get one statistic value for each feature type. Is this even possible in QGIS? If not, is there another way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can use **SAGA - Raster Statistics for Polygons** tool. It is accessible from `QGIS Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector <-> raster`. And a key message  is "*Use multipart polygon*".

Overview of the workflow is like a picture below:
[image]

Each step is:

**1)** Create Multipart polygon

1. Open the attribute table of your `feature "12"` and create a new field `group` and give a same number (such as `1`) to all polygons.
2. Activate `Singleparts to multipart` tool (from menu; `Vector | Geometry tool`)
3. (1) Input layer is your `feature "12"`
4. (2) Select the `group` field you have just created. All polygons which has same `group` number are put together.

**2)** Calculate statistics (Q90)

1. Activate **Raster statistics for polygons** tool.
2. (3) Select your raster layer in `Grids`
3. (4) Select `Multipart` layer from above step.
4. (5) Ignore all statistics you do not need.
5. (6) Enter `10` in the `Quantiles` (*Do not enter `90`*). This `10` is the quantile interval, so you will obtain Q10, Q20, ..., Q90. .
6. Run this tool.

Comment: Thankyou. I am using QGIS 2.18 and do not have the Raster statistics for Polygons tool.

Comment: @AmieLastName I am also using QGIS 2.18. It is in the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Am I able to add screen shots in here? It is not in my Processing Toolbox and it does not come up when I search. Am I perhaps missing a plug-in?

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. As stated, I did not have 'The raster statistics for polygons' tool visible in my QGIS install. After troubleshooting and researching similar issues online, a suggestion was to remove and reinstall my QGIS installation.  This I did and lo and behold, I could see additional Processing Tools, including the one mentioned above. Your solution and instructions given above answered my question perfectly once I could use the tool.

Comment: Great, thanks @AmieLastName Sorry I did not know the cause, but glad to know you had managed it.